# Low reflectance values

Tags: raster, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, reflectance, opendronemap, dji

I use DJI P4 multispectral. Here is the command I gave in opendronemap software.

```
–dem-resolution 1.5 --orthophoto-resolution 1.5
–orthophoto-png --dsm
–radiometric-calibration camera
–texturing-skip-global-seam-leveling
–pc-quality high
```

The reflectance values are very low. what might be the reason for this?[image]